# Spring service and repository layer convention

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, naming-conventions

I start working with Spring and have some confusions about its conventions.

1. Is it fine to put Repositories in Controller?
2. In a Service class, If I want to reuse code could I inject other `Services` and **other Reposities**?
3. is it the best practice to name `Service` And `Repository` class is based on `Entity` name i.e: User -> `UserRepository`->`UserService`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. No, don't use Repositories in the Controller. Only in the Services.
   And don't use Entities in your Controller. Create Dto (Data Transfer
   Objects) Object from the Entities and work with this in your
   frontend

   2. Yes you can use other services and respositories in your service class
   3. Yes it is. Name the interfache UserService and the implementation UserServiceImpl

Comment: 1. _"don't use Entities in your Controller"_ You mean I should convert `Entities` to Dto in `Service` before I return? Or In `Controller` I should get `Entities` from `Service` then convert them to Dto before I transfer data to view? <br/>

Comment: I mean you have to convert the entities to dto's in your service. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object. can you please flag my answer as accepted?

Answer (score 1):

Check also answer:

It explains the Persistence Bussines and Presentation layers

https://stackoverflow.com/a/34084807/2218992