# Proper way for passing data from controller to view in spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have two entities

```
public class FooEntity1 {
   private Integer id;
   private Collection<FooEntity2> entities;
   //gettrs, setters
}

public class FooEntity2 {
   private Integer id;
   private String msg;
   private String name;
   //gettrs, setters
}
```

In controller I have an object 'foo' of class FooEntity1 which has a few objects in collection 'entities'.

In JSP file I'd like to do something like this

```
<c:forEach items="${foo.entities}" var="entity">
  ${entity.id} - ${entity.msg} - ${entity.name}
</c:forEach>
```

I know that it's bad idea to pass entity object to jsp file, so here my question: what is proper way for using data from entities in view? I have two ideas:

1. put data from entities in Map and pass it to view
2. create FooEntity1Dto and FooEntity2Dto classes to pass data to view

How should I do that?

Comment: It's not a bad idea to pass entities to the view. Just pass them, and understand what happens when accessing properties and associations of entities.

Answer (score 0):

The second idea is better, i.e., create Dto for view logic.

You are right that passing the entity to the JSP is a bad idea.

It violates single responsibility. Entity is an object for persistent; however, for each view, there could be different view logic and it will require different Dto. If you reuse Entity, it may save your time in the start, but you will find your Entity will mix with a lots of transient getter in the future, which makes the class very difficult to be maintained.

Comment: thanks for answer. I've found this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34084203/spring-entities-should-convert-to-dto-in-service Thomas maintain that it would be perfect to have three classes for each type of object (FooEntity , Foo , FooDto). I see that in big projects (a few teams) it's good idea, but I wonder if it's 'necessary' in small projects ( < 5 contributors). what do you think?

Comment: @jker I am sure whether the Foo class will work in a web application. But his point is similar to Martin Fowler's this article: https://www.martinfowler.com/bliki/AnemicDomainModel.html, which talks about these entity beans without behaviors

Comment: @jker typo: not sure, :)